# Connect css fonts locally

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I searched on the Internet how to connect fonts to the site, with a link to a local file, but could not find a complete answer anywhere. Please explain by points and in full what needs to be done to connect fonts to HTML and CSS files.

Comment: does your issue resolved ?

Answer (score 1):

You can go through with following steps

```
Step 1: Download the font
Step 2: Create a WebFont Kit for cross-browsing
Step 3: Upload the font files to your website
Step 4: Update and upload your CSS file
Step 5: Use the custom font in your CSS declarations.
```

for reference please check below link

https://www.pagecloud.com/blog/how-to-add-custom-fonts-to-any-website

Hope this will help :) Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this css to add your personalized fonts

@font-face {

```
 font-family:'Your Font Name Here';

 src:url('path-to-your-font.ttf') format('truetype');
```

}

Good Luck.